# Hiding feathered edges when using CSS-Filters-Polyfill

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find a workaround a problem which I'm encountering when using blur feature in CSS-Filters-Polyfill (https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill). When the content is blurred, I'm getting a feathered or blurred edges and I'm trying to achieve a sharp edge all the way around the blurred content.

I've addressed this to the Polyfilter's author and he suggested to apply overflow:hidden to a parent container. This helped, but when if the ratio of the browser is changing, it still shows feathered left and right sides of the container with the red background peeking through.

Here's the example of what I'm cooking http://codepen.io/0leg/full/CzLIF. If the image has sharp edge all around, reduce the height of your browser window while keeping the sides as wide as you can.

Code snippet credit: Codrops - Nifty Modal Window Effects